# To show content as links

Tags: views, nodes, navigation

I want to display 10 contents of same content type as links in a single view. Is it possible? How?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Yes, that's the most basic thing that Views does. What tutorials/learning resources have you used to teach yourself about Views? I find it strange that none of them have mentioned the most basic use of the module. Please do some research into this yourself, read some tutorials, try a few things, and _then_ ask questions here if you can't work it out yourself. But please be sure to include detailed descriptions of what you've already tried yourself in the question; we don't run a support forum here and requests for full tutorials don't fit out format. Thanks

Comment: I have tried it for 20 times in this week. I already told I am a newbie to drupal. Just posted this questions since I have not find any useful ans in tutorials I watched. I dont have the names of them sorry. One more suggestion... Things look like basic to you may be advanced to somebody.

Comment: It doesn't matter that you're a beginner to Drupal, you can still take the time and effort to construct a good question. You are getting support for free from professional developers, if someone politely recommends that you actually make an effort _I_ would suggest you heed that advice. We want **high quality** questions and answers here, and we will always make sure that low quality contributions are highlighted as such in the short term to serve as a deterrent from people posting more poor quality content, then eventually we delete them as they serve no purpose...

Comment: ...as I mentioned this is not a support forum, it's a Q+A site for high quality content. If you want to tap into the excellent resources available to you here, you are naturally expected to follow the rules like everybody else. Please bear all this in mind when posting in the future. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[views](https://drupal.org/project/views) is the module you are looking for. It will allow you to list your contents filtered by content type as links. Look at [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1z13ylwMhk4) before you start.

Comment: Thanks it was helpful.I have already installed views module. In tutorial I found how to display the content title alone. Thanks.